# How to get event logs in web3.py v3.*?

Tags: web3.py

I would like to listen to events on a contract, but I'm having trouble figuring out which of the interfaces is the correct one and finding an example on how to use it.

The way I see it:

- [Contract.eventFilter](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.eventFilter) is `v4` only
- [Contract.pastEvents](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.pastEvents) is `v3` only
- [LogFilter](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#web3.utils.filters.LogFilter) is `v3` only and marked as deprecated, pointing to:
- [LogFilter.get_all_entries](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html#web3.utils.filters.LogFilter.get_all_entries) - `v4` only
- [LogFilter.get](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#web3.utils.filters.LogFilter.get) is only in `v3`
- and there are [many many more...](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html)

The most promising is combination of [Eth.filter](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.filter) with either:

- [Eth.getFilterChanges](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.getFilterChanges) for listening to new events or
- [Eth.getFilterLogs](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.getFilterLogs) for fetching them from history.

Which method should I use so that it will keep working once `v4` comes out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it. The best way to be compatible with both is to use either of:

- `w3.eth.getFilterChanges()`
- `w3.eth.getFilterLogs()`

The good news is that the work is reusable. You'll probably want some kind of polling thread to get the filter changes in `v3`, and a similar thread will be useful in a port to `v4`.

The bad news is that it's one of the least convenient ways to write filters. I would suggest to go straight to `v4` now, but filters in particular need a lot of love in the beta. Block and transaction filters are simply broken at the moment: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/pull/490

---

If you're feeling really motivated, you could cherry-pick the changes from [this PR](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/pull/346) back to the `v3` branch. Then you could write the `v4`-compatible filter code in `v3`.

Comment: I can handle if it's not the most convenient way, I just wasn't sure if it was the right one. I have tried using `v4.0.0b3` but unfortunately the address format has changed to `HexBytes`, which somehow breaks my call to `debug_traceTransaction` to get the internal transactions... Also, I had some problems with addresses' CRC but I was able to avoid that. Anyway, I'll take a look at `v4` later, but right now I have to make these tests work... :) Thank you for the directions, I appreciate it!

Comment: @johndodo For the next time you want to attempt the v4 beta: `HexBytes` are really just `bytes`, with a pretty representation in the terminal. You can convert from `bytes` (and therefore `HexBytes`) to the hex string representation with `Web3.toHex(transaction_hash)`.

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks - I just didn't have the time to look into it yet. :)

Answer (score 7):

The solution I used is:

```
import web3

w3 = web3.Web3(web3.HTTPProvider(url))

event_signature_transfer = web3.Web3.sha3(text='Transfer(address,address,uint256)')
event_filter = w3.eth.filter({'topics': [event_signature_transfer]})
transfer_events = w3.eth.getFilterChanges(event_filter.filter_id)

# ... do something ...

new_transfer_events = w3.eth.getFilterChanges(event_filter.filter_id)
```

Hope it helps someone.